# accessing nested dict from list of keys

Tags: python

I have a a nested dict object with N layers:

```
d={'l0':{'l1':{'l2':...}}}
```

in addition, I have a list of all the dict keys:

```
k=['l0','l1','l2',...]
```

how can I access the element defined by the list,for an arbitrary list, that is:

```
d[k[0]][k[1]][k[2]].... = X
```

(I would like a function that return the reference to the data...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is the following:

```
def resolve_value(obj, keys):
    for key in keys:
        obj = obj[key]
    return obj


k = ['l0', 'l1', 'l2']
d = {'l0': {'l1': {'l2': 'hello'}}}

print(resolve_value(d, k))
```

**Output**

```
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the intuitive solution:

```
val = d
for key in k:
   val = val[key]
# operations with val here
```